# como fazer pra que o sempre mostre o ultimo elemento adicionado em uma div usando JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, rolamento

estou criando um mini chatbox e quando a div das conversas está cheia os ultimos elementos adicionados fica escondidos e precisa dar scroll manualmente. Preciso que quando adicionar o ultimo item de um scroll automaticamente para o fim.

```js
const texto = document.querySelector('.texto')
const chat = document.querySelector('.chat')
let digitado = ''

function send() {
    chat.innerHTML += `
        <div class="typed-text">
            ${texto.value}
        </div>
        `
    setTimeout(geraResposta, 1000)
}

function geraResposta(){
    digitado = texto.value.toLowerCase()
    if(digitado === "q"){
        chat.innerHTML += `
          <div class="texto-resposta">
          teste "Q"
          </div>
          `
    }
}
```

```css
.chat{
    width: 330px;
    height: 420px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Faltou o HTML para tornar o exemplo testável.

Comment: Importante sempre fornecer um [mcve] em vez de trechos soltos (lembrando que o site tem o recurso de snippets de código). Ainda, a pesquisa é importante para ver se o assunto não foi tratado ainda (o próprio quadro de "relacionados" ao lado da postagem já tem algo nesse sentido). A [help] pode ajudar num uso mais eficaz do site.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Para rolar automaticamente para o fim da div sempre que um novo elemento for adicionado, você pode usar a propriedade scrollTop da div. O scrollTop é o valor da posição superior da div em relação ao topo da janela de visualização e pode ser usado para rolar para cima ou para baixo a div usando JavaScript.

Aqui está um exemplo de como atualizar o scrollTop para o valor máximo sempre que um novo elemento é adicionado à div:

```js
function send() {
    chat.innerHTML += `
        <div class="typed-text">
            ${texto.value}
        </div>
    `;
    chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight; // atualiza o scrollTop para o valor máximo
    setTimeout(geraResposta, 1000);
}

function geraResposta(){
    digitado = texto.value.toLowerCase();
    if(digitado === "q"){
        chat.innerHTML += `
            <div class="texto-resposta">
                teste "Q"
            </div>
        `;
        chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight; // atualiza o scrollTop para o valor máximo
    }
}
```

Ao adicionar um novo elemento à div, você atualiza o scrollTop para o valor máximo (chat.scrollHeight), o que faz com que a div role automaticamente para o fim. Isso garante que o usuário sempre veja o último elemento adicionado.

Comment: Evite promoção pessoal nos posts, pois isso pode ser sinalizado como spam, resultando em penalização pelo próprio sistema do site. Tomei a liberdade de editar e remover o link, mas evite nas próximas. Mais informações na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), especialmente na seção "Evite promoção pessoal flagrante"

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Coloquei o chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight e deu certo.